# Is First-order logic Turing complete?

Tags: predicate-logic, first-order-logic, computability, turing-machines

Is [First-order logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-order_logic) also called predicate logic [Turing complete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_completeness)?

EDIT:
If we do computation by checking if premises logically entail a conclusion. And the method is [resolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resolution_(logic)) .

Comment: Do you have some particular way of treating first-order logic as a method of computation in mind?  Without one, the question is meaningless...

Comment: @EricWofsey We do computation by checking if premises logically entail the conclusion. And the method is resolution https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resolution_(logic)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You seem to be asking whether you can use the deductive rules of first-order logic to simulate a Turing machine. One possible answer is yes, in the following sense: You can use the elements $s$ of a structure to represent steps in a computation, a series of predicates $P(s)$ to represent the state at that step, and a group of first-order axioms such as $P(s) \rightarrow Q(s+1)$ to initialize the state and govern the transitions. If you do this correctly, your Turing machine halts iff you can use these axioms to prove $(\exists s)[s$ is configured in a halting state$]$. But there are also other ways to interpret your question.

Comment: I've noticed that you wrote this answer 1 year into your presidency. Now that your presidency is over and you presumably have some more time on your hand, would you be willing to explain these other ways to interpret the question?

Answer (score 3):

[[Some Turing-Complete Extensions of First-Order Logic]](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1405.1715.pdf), by Antti Kuusisto, contains the following remark in the second paragraph:

> A crucial weakness in the expressivity of k-th order predicate logic
>   is that only a finite amount of information can be encoded by a finite
>   number of quantified relations over a finite domain. Intuitively,
>   there is no infinitely expandable memory available. **Thus k-th order**
>   **logic is not Turing-complete**.

Comment: This is pretty misleading.  The question as asked is meaningless, because there is no obvious way in which first order logic can be considered as a computational system at all.  The paper you linked gives a certain definition for this but I highly doubt this is what the asker of this question had in mind.

Answer (score 3):

Interpreting your question as is there an isomorphism between first order logic and a Turing complete system of computation/calculus, then no. The [Curry-Howard Isomorphism](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curry%E2%80%93Howard_correspondence) shows it is merely isomorphic to Lambda-P, so it does need extended to be Isomorphic to something Turing complete. The more expressive Real PCF (Programming Computable Functions) extended with the existential quantifier is an example of a more expressive extension of simply typed lambda-calculus that is Turing-Complete [1][2]. This is similar to how how second-order predicate logic is more expressive than first order predicate logic and isomorphic to a more expressive computational model [Lambda-P2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_cube#Relation_to_other_systems).

One class of deductive systems isomorphic to Lambda-Calculus in general (and thus Turing-Complete) and closely related to first-order logic is the class of Hilbert-style deduction systems. This is more expressive than first-order logic because it can be used to prove meta-logical results including ones about first-order logic not provable within first-order logic. First-order logic doesn’t allow trans finite induction, but other Hilbert-style deductions can. This is similar to how general recursion is a fundamental aspect of Turing-Complete systems. This is also related to [Combinatory Logic](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatory_logic) (not to be confused with Combinational Logic)

[1]: M.H. Escardó.
Real PCF extended with $\exists$ is universal.
In A. Edalat, S. Jourdan, and G. McCusker, editors, Advances in Theory and Formal Methods of Computing: Proceedings of the Third Imperial College Workshop, April 1996, pages 13-24, Christ Church, Oxford, 1996. IC Press.
[2]: https://www.lfcs.inf.ed.ac.uk/reports/97/ECS-LFCS-97-374/ECS-LFCS-97-374.pdf